# Robust programming using stdio (from a posix user's perspective)

Tags: c, file, posix, stdio, libc

I'm trying to work out how to use FILE objects correctly, after coming from pure posix. I feel like I'm missing the point somehow.

Please could someone give me, from start to finish, an example of the correct way to write using fprintf() and fwrite(), ensuring that all data is written correctly and flushed and dealing with any non-fatal errors accordingly. For example, what happens to ferror() if you get an EINTR on the underlying file descriptor during fwrite, and what happens if you fill the FILE object's buffer?

context: I have a program critical pipe, if it goes down then I have to restart the entire process, so I want to know with certainty how to differentiate between "please retry", "libc error not related to file descriptor" and "your file descriptor is pining for the fjords". I'm trying to avoid re-factoring existing code to use pure posix if possible, but I don't feel like I've found a comprehensive description of stdio FILE edge cases up to this point. Tried grepping gcc (4.1.1) source for fwrite, the trail went dead at fwrite_unlocked.

Comment: The standard I/O functions are not really part of the compiler, but of the standard library (e.g. glibc on Linux platforms). For a good reference see e.g. [this site here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Comment: You know, C standard I/O functions are POSIX functions (because the whole standard was incorporated by reference, with additional guarantees).

Comment: I'd go for refactoring. If it's mission critical I always use the raw system calls. They are so much more simple and reliable. `write()` just writes.